# How to update AWS Athena with the latest file in S3 using Glue Crawler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I use AWS Glue Crawler to insert data to Athena from S3 Data Source. Initially, I have a JSON file in my S3 Data Source as shown in the below diagram. [image]

The content of this "quizstatus1.json" JSON file is

```
{ "id" : 50, "name":"John", "quiz_status": "In Progress" }
{ "id" : 51, "name":"Jane", "quiz_status": "In Progress" }
{ "id" : 53, "name":"Jill", "quiz_status": "In Progress" }
```

This gets uploaded to AWS Athena as expected when the Glue Crawler is run.
[image]

However, the problem comes when a new JSON file is added to my S3 data source. The new JSON file contains the latest information and the Athena needs to be updated with content of this latest JSON file which is "quizstatus2.json" as per this case. [image].

The content of this new "quizstatus2.json" JSON file is

```
{ "id" : 50, "name":"John", "quiz_status": "Completed" }
{ "id" : 51, "name":"Jane", "quiz_status": "In Progress" }
{ "id" : 53, "name":"Jill", "quiz_status": "Completed" }
```

When I run the Glue Crawler, Athena shows data of the "quizstatus1.json" as well as "quizstatus2.json" file as shown below in the diagram.
[image]

I only want to Athena be updated with the content in "quizstatus2.json" file only and I don't want the data of "quizstatus1.json" to be available in Athena. So basically I want to update the Athena with the latest file added to the S3 Data Source. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena does not need to "be updated".

When a table is created in Amazon Athena, or the AWS Glue Catalog, it has a `location` parameter that tells Athena where the data is stored in Amazon S3.

Then, when a query is run in Amazon Athena, it will look at all files in that location, including subdirectories.

Therefore, to update the information used by Athena, simply add or replace the files in that location. The files will be used for subsequent queries in Athena. The AWS Glue crawler does not need to be re-run, since all it does is define the table and its location. Neither of those attributes have changed.

If you do not want the earlier file to be included in the Athena query, then you should either delete it, or overwrite it with the data that you *do* want to appear. Note that *all files* in that directory will be included in queries.